# SparkR - Convert dataframe into Vector

Tags: r, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I'm exploring SparkR to compute statistics like quantiles, mean, frequency of categories (source file is in Amazon S3 - csv format).

I'm able to parse the csv file and create a dataframe.
However, I'm not able to use this spark-dataframe with standard R functions like, `quantile(), mean()` etc.

For an example, here is the R dataframe 'test'

```
> test <- data.frame(x=c(26,21,20),y=c(34,29,28))
> quantile ( test$x )
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
20.0 20.5 21.0 23.5 26.0
```

Above dataframe produces right result. However, the dataframe created via `read.df()` isn't working with `quantile()` function.

```
> myDf = read.df(sqlContext, "s3n://path/s3file.csv", , source="com.databricks.spark.csv")
> quantile ( myDf$column1 )
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(<S4 object of class "Column">) :
  is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
2: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'S4'
Error in x[order(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing)] : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'i' in selecting a method for function '[': Error in x[!nas] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

My question is simple, is there anyway use the SparkR's dataframe with the native R functions? Or how to convert SparkR dataframe into a vector.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would appear `read.df` creates an S4 object ([example link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to apply native R functions on SparkR DataFrames.  The easiest way is to make your DataFrame local by

```
localDf <- collect(myDf)
```

On this data.frame you can apply native R functions, but not in a distributed way.  When you did alter your localDf to localDf2 with native R functions, you could convert it back into a SparkR DataFrame with

```
myDf2 <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, localDF2)
```